# Compare 2 successful results

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

This results instances listed with ELB:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name XXXXXXX --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[].Instances[].InstanceId'
```

I need some help in writing a script, which checks for new aws instances attached to the ELB.
- Need to compare the present result and previous results, which helps us to get the new instance info.

Comment: We may be having language difficulty, but I'm confused what it is you are wanting to do. `"checks for new aws instances attached to the ELB"` -- well, what is the `new aws instance` and what is the ELB they are attached to? Are you asking for a check of `"aws elb ..."` at the beginning of your example line of text?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin
`aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name XXXXXXX --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[].Instances[].InstanceId'`
It check for present existing attached instances with ELB.


-  I want to store the result to a file or a variable
-  In the next run, if there any new instance attached to ELB, then the script should compare the present and previous results and results in the new instance info.

Hoping it makes sense.

Comment: If you have multiple lines in that format, then you may want to store the results of the pipeline in a variable, e.g. `current=$(aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name XXXXXXX --region us-east-1 | jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[].Instances[].InstanceId')` then make the comparison as needed and then before you get the next line set `prev="$current"` to save current as previous, and then go handle the next line, etc... and repeat until you run out of lines. But the part I'm still unclear on is just what you want to do with them and what your comparison is.

Comment: There are some chances of adding additional instances to our ELB's, without notice. To monitor ELB and its instances attached, we are thinking to write a Nagios plugin to monitor that.

Comment: Here is the script:
---
>#Get instance info on the ELB
>result_file=$(mktemp /tmp/$elb.XXXXXX)
>aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name $elb --region $region | jq -r '.LoadBalancerDescriptions[].Instances[].InstanceId' > $result_file ;

>#Latest old file with instances on elb
>old=$(ls -lrt /tmp/ |grep "$elb\."|tail -n2|head -1|awk '{print $NF}')

>#latest files with instances on elb
>latest=$(ls -lrt /tmp/ |grep "$elb\."|tail -n2|tail -1|awk '{print $NF}')

>#output file
>op_file=$(mktemp /tmp/op-file.XXXXXX)

>diff /tmp/$old /tmp/$latest > $op_file

---

Comment: ```if [ -s $op_file ]; then
        #Instance list with comma(,) separator
        result=$(echo -n $(cat $op_file |grep  ">" |cut -d'>' -f2))
        echo "WARNING: New instances:$result has added to ELB: $elb"
 exit $ST_WR;
        else
        echo "OK: No new instances has added to ELB: $elb"
 exit $ST_OK;
fi
fi```